# PowerShell: variables in transaction manifest doesn't work

Tags: scrypto

I am trying to run a transaction manifest that contains variables (for example `ComponentAddress("${my_account}")`) but when I run it with `resim run [manifest_file]` it doesn't get replaced with the value stored in the environment variables. By the way I am using the PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you should set the environment variables like this:

```
$env:my_account="[account_address]"
```

(don't forget the `$env:` part)